# How to get the previous focus and compare strings

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

How can I get the previous focus/be able to compare strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN event contains also a reference to the interactive object losing the focus (relatedObject property).

In your code you could change:

```
textbox[i].addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
textbox[i].tabIndex= i;
```

to:

```
textbox[i].addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
textbox[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, handleFocusIn);
textbox[i].tabIndex= i; 

function handleFocusIn(anEvent: FocusEvent): void
{
  if (anEvent.relatedObject is TextField)
  {
     var previousBox: TextField = anEvent.relatedObject as TextField;
     var currentBox: TextField = anEvent.target as TextField;
     // etc.
  }
}
```

Like the previous answer said, try to figure out how looping works. Also you can reference the TextField using []:

```
// to reference names_mc.box19_txt using an index
var index: int = 19;
var textbox: TextField = names_mc['box' + index + '_txt'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for the `FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT` event; you can learn more in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3afocusOut).

But seriously, you should learn basic [repetition constructs like a loop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html) first.  No one should *ever* have two arrays that look like that ;-)

Comment: I'm working on the loops now. Thank you!  do you know how I could check the previous focus by any chance?